# Mysql cp850 charset - Illegal mix of collation

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a string comparison case sensitive in MySQL (5.6).

```
select * from myTable where name like '% Web' COLLATE cp850_bin;
```

And I get this error :

```
ERROR 1267 (HY000) at [...]: 
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (cp850_bin,EXPLICIT) for
operation 'like'
```

Here is some infos that may be relevant :

```
>DESC myTable;
+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)           | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(255)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

>show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                                   |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | cp850                                                   |
| character_set_connection | cp850                                                   |
| character_set_database   | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                                  |
| character_set_results    | cp850                                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8                                                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                                    |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+

>show COLLATION WHERE Charset = 'cp850';
+------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+
| Collation        | Charset | Id | Default | Compiled | Sortlen |
+------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+
| cp850_general_ci | cp850   |  4 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
| cp850_bin        | cp850   | 80 |         | Yes      |       1 |
+------------------+---------+----+---------+----------+---------+

>show COLLATION WHERE Charset = 'utf8';
+--------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| Collation                | Charset | Id  | Default | Compiled | Sortlen |
+--------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
| utf8_general_ci          | utf8    |  33 | Yes     | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8_bin                 | utf8    |  83 |         | Yes      |       1 |
| utf8_unicode_ci          | utf8    | 192 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_icelandic_ci        | utf8    | 193 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_latvian_ci          | utf8    | 194 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_romanian_ci         | utf8    | 195 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_slovenian_ci        | utf8    | 196 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_polish_ci           | utf8    | 197 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_estonian_ci         | utf8    | 198 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_spanish_ci          | utf8    | 199 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_swedish_ci          | utf8    | 200 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_turkish_ci          | utf8    | 201 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_czech_ci            | utf8    | 202 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_danish_ci           | utf8    | 203 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_lithuanian_ci       | utf8    | 204 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_slovak_ci           | utf8    | 205 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_spanish2_ci         | utf8    | 206 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_roman_ci            | utf8    | 207 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_persian_ci          | utf8    | 208 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_esperanto_ci        | utf8    | 209 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_hungarian_ci        | utf8    | 210 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_sinhala_ci          | utf8    | 211 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_german2_ci          | utf8    | 212 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_croatian_ci         | utf8    | 213 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_unicode_520_ci      | utf8    | 214 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_vietnamese_ci       | utf8    | 215 |         | Yes      |       8 |
| utf8_general_mysql500_ci | utf8    | 223 |         | Yes      |       1 |
+--------------------------+---------+-----+---------+----------+---------+
```

Does anyone have a clue on what I can do to solve this error, I can't find any topic related to this error and cp850 charset (Nothing on the web, nor on SO)

Thanks